# Python class in c++ using the cython?

Tags: python, c++

it is possible to create a program which is written in python and C++ by using cython
How would you use this class written in python (if possible) inside some cpp file (which uses the "calcuations" function, and prints "happy birthday"), by using cython?

file1.py:-

```
class mathClass:

def __init__(self,number):
    self.number = number

def calcuations(self):
    self.number = self.number + 1
    print(self.number)

math = mathClass(10)
```

Edit

Don't miss understand me, but "have you heard about cython" is often mentioned in stackoverflow, and I did some research, and by my understading (I beg you, correct me if I am wrong), cython is a language which is similar to python and can be interpreted by c++ or by python, but I am not sure if it can actually be used to link python to c++ (I didn't managed to find any tutorials/examples)

Comment: You might want to check out Cython http://cython.org/.  There's a learning curve but it's a very powerful language.

Comment: I know of the other way around.. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/python/doc/

Comment: I did, and by my understading (plz correct me if I am wrong), cython is a language which is similar to python and can be interpreted by c++ or by python, but I am not sure if it can link python to c++ (I didn't managed to find any tutorials/examples) 
response to Paul cornelius

Comment: Have you tried [swig](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html)? It is easy to use and the learning curve is not that hard.

Comment: @MeHow Cython can be used to link Python to C/C++.  Cython code is syntactically similar to Python so it cannot be run through a C/C++ compiler.  Example Cython to C++: http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html